# Ajax request takes too long

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm asking you, because I dont have any ideas...

I've made an ajax request which gets a small data from the server. The json answer is already cached by the server, so it's pretty fast.

Like

```
window.xhr = $.ajax({
url: domain+'index.php?fx_action=ajax&fx_mode=continents&fx_type=countries&fx_ajaxid='+window.currentajaxrequest+'&fx_id='+window.id+'&fx_page='+(window.page-1)+'&fx_pager='+window.pager+'&fx_order='+window.order,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
timeout: 5000,
cache: false,
async: true,
beforeSend: function () {
        ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        return false;
    },
    success: function (data) {  
        ...
```

But the answer time is sliding on a huge scale, sometimes it takes for 1 sec sometimes just 67 millisecs...

```
continents.js:65  http://teszt.domain.com/index.php?fx_action=ajax&fx_mode=continents&fx_type=countries&fx_ajaxid=0&fx_id=6&fx_page=1&fx_pager=9&fx_order=name
continents.js:100 start: 0
continents.js:101 beforesend: 9
continents.js:102 success: 5087
continents.js:103 complete: 5096
continents.js:65  http://teszt.domain.com/index.php?fx_action=ajax&fx_mode=continents&fx_type=countries&fx_ajaxid=1&fx_id=6&fx_page=2&fx_pager=9&fx_order=name
continents.js:100 start: 0
continents.js:101 beforesend: 9
continents.js:102 success: 70
continents.js:103 complete: 77
continents.js:65  http://teszt.domain.com/index.php?fx_action=ajax&fx_mode=continents&fx_type=countries&fx_ajaxid=2&fx_id=6&fx_page=3&fx_pager=9&fx_order=name
continents.js:100 start: 0
continents.js:101 beforesend: 11
continents.js:102 success: 301
continents.js:103 complete: 304
```

In getting the same data structure with almost same size in kbytes. And everything is cached by the server.

In the server side the php's running time always about 30-40ms. What is my mistake?

Comment: I have a similar problem on a locally running webserver. I'd imagine that it would be much faster, but amazingly some websites have better performance than it!

Comment: Maybe a slow server? Maybe a torrent client running on your test PC, that clutters all connections (sure that I've had this problem :D )

Comment: The browser does a limited number of requests to the same server in parallel only. Depending on the number of congruent requests, this can vary as some requests are need to wait before they are performed.

Comment: It's possible you're just having fluctuations in network speed on your own computer at home that you are viewing the page from.

Comment: 100MByte in out, the server is limited for me noone else can reach it. And i'e got 120Mbit/80Mbit/s internet connection. It must be enough in any way, to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from spikes in network speed and performance on your server, it's possible you're coming up against the limit of 2 active connections to the same host name in the browser.  A few questions:

- Do you have other requests that could be running concurrently?
- Is this script running on page startup?  If so, it could be sword fighting with other resource requests.

I would suggesting taking a look at the net panel in firebug to check out what else is going on while your request is being made.

Comment: 1) No, I do not. 2) Nop it binds with click. Like: `$(".pager span").live("click", function(){ if (window.returnedajaxrequest != window.currentajaxrequest) {window.xhr.abort();} if (($(this).hasClass("mod")) && !($(this).hasClass("disabled"))) { if ($(this).attr("rel") == "f") { window.page = 1; showCountries(); ... etc.`